# How to use FLANN for labeling and clustering?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, flann, cbir

I read a paper that their retrieval system is based on SIFT descriptor and [fast approximate k-means clustering](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/). I installed `pyflann`. If I am not mistaken the following commands only find the indices of the close datapoints to a specific sample (for example, here, the indices of 5 nearest points from `dataset` to `testset`)

```
from pyflann import *
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import *
dataset = rand(10000, 128)
testset = rand(1000, 128)
flann = FLANN()
result,dists = flann.nn(dataset,testset,5,algorithm="kmeans",
branching=32, iterations=7, checks=16)
```

I went through user manual, however, could find how can I do `k-means` clusterin with `FLANN`. and How can I fit the test based on the cluster centers. As we can use the `kmeans++` clustering` in [scikitlearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), and then we are fitting the dataset based on the model:

```
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=100,init='k-means++',random_state = 0, verbose=0)
kmeans.fit(dataset)
```

and later we can assign labels to the test set by using `KDTree` for example.

```
kdt=KDTree(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
Q=testset  #query
kdt_dist,kdt_idx=kdt.query(Q,k=1)  #knn
test_labels=kdt_idx  #knn=1 labels
```

Could someone please help me how can I use the same procedure with `FLANN`? (I mean clustering the dataset (finding the cluster centers and quantizing features) and then quantizing testset based on cluster centers found from the previous step).

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do the best variations with FLANN, because these use two indexes at the same time, and are ugly to implement.

But you can build a new index on the centers for every iteration. But unless you have k > 1000 it probably will not help much.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could I ask what is the usage of FLANN? and what exactly `flann.nn()` function is doing? I used it for the coordinates (x,y) of points in dataset and test set by this`flann.nn(dataset,testset, 5, algorithm="kdtree")` to obtain the 5 neareset points. Is it correct or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that I use FLANN which is set with `kmeans` algorithm and quantize SIFT feature with that, by assigning 2000 as number of clusters? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.